# Google Chrome Installation

Tags: google-chrome

How do I install Google Chrome on my Ubuntu 13.10 easily? I had downloaded the file called google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb from google downloads but it doesnot install using Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 2):

Open a Terminal and go to the folder where you downloaded the deb file an type:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

It will install the package system-wide.

Comment: If you get an error about unmet dependencies or the package not configuring, you can run `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix the installation. It will install the missing packages as well as the last one you attempted to install.

Answer (score 0):

Add 3rd party repository for Google Chrome stable with these commands:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

<sub>**Source:** https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome</sub>

Answer (score 0):

For Installing chrome in Kubuntu 14.04, open KONSOLE then run the following commands

```
cd /tmp
```

For 32 bit :

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

For 64 bit :

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*; sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to download folder where that chromium.deb file is downloaded.
2. right click and open terminal.
3. wrote command to extract file.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
   ```
4. now install the pakage using below command.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```

After installation search for chromium application and you see it is installed in system.